# Node xml2js is returning 'undefined' when using parseString()

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I'm using this package elsewhere and it's working just fine, however in one particular example with one XML file I'm getting "undefined" errors.

Example:

```
fs.readFile('./XML/theXMLfile13mb.xml', 'ascii', function(err,data){
    if(err) {
        console.log("Could not open file " + err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result); // Returns undefined
        var json1 = JSON.stringify(result); // Gives an error
        var json = JSON.parse(json1);
```

[The `xml2js` docs](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) don't really mention how this might be possible/what this might mean. I've tried using other XML files and they work fine. This particular XML file is no bigger than the others nor does it appear to be any less in-tact (it opens fine in my browser and all the data is presented as expected).

Any ideas on how I could troubleshoot this?

Comment: Make sure the XML has 100% valid syntax. Also verify the file encoding.

Comment: Beyond opening it in the browser and seeing it load correctly with no errors, how would I do this?

Comment: Run it through an XML validator (although I think that most browsers should indicate grossly invalid XML).

Comment: you could see an `err` param in the `parseString` function's callback. What did it say on `console.log`?

Comment: Wild guess is your file loading to data ? Remove the `ascii` encoding, default `utf8` should be sufficient.

Comment: add `if (err) console.log(err)` before doing anything with the parsed result. Let us know which error is printed too. And removing `'ascii'` as @user568109 said is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `data` from a Buffer to a String, use this:

```
parseString(data.toString(), function (err, result) {
```

Instead of:

```
parseString(data, function (err, result) {
```